# Audit transacctions with oracle and nodejs with pool typeorm

Tags: node.js, oracle, node.js-typeorm

How to audit transactions in a node js application with oracle where the connection is made with a single user, and all DML operations are registered with the same connection user, knowing that oracle handles users, permissions for tables and audits on these users.

Comment: are you using the node-oracledb add-on for Node.js ?

Comment: yes with typeorm

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be to use `node-oracledb` add-on for `node.js` which contains the necessary methods for the connection class.

```
const connection = await oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    user          : "hr",
    password      : mypw,  // mypw contains the hr schema password
    connectString : "localhost/orclpdb1"
  }
);

connection.clientId = "Chris";
connection.clientInfo = "My demo application";
connection.module = "End-to-end example";
connection.action = "Query departments";
connection.dbOp   = "Billing"

const result = await connection.execute(`SELECT . . .`);
```

You can then easily store these values anywhere you want, as they are available by accessing `v$session`

```
SQL> SELECT username, client_identifier, client_info, action, module FROM v$session WHERE username = 'HR';

USERNAME   CLIENT_IDENTIFIER    CLIENT_INFO            ACTION               MODULE
---------- -------------------- ---------------------- -------------------- --------------------
HR         Chris                My demo application    Query departments    End-to-end example
```

And in `v$sql_monitor`

```
SQL> SELECT dbop_name FROM v$sql_monitor;
DBOP_NAME
------------------------------
Billing
```

After that, you need to evaluate which audit activities you want to record and store in the database:

- If you want only to store `logon` and `logout` of each of these end users, you may use a logon trigger and a logoff trigger.
- If you want to audit specific actions of these users, you need to enable the corresponding `audit` features at session level, table level, etc...

Comment: Ok, this begins to give me ideas but also other doubts. The management of the connection is handled directly by TypeORM, remember that it opens the connection as soon as the application starts and the users begin to consume the pool, but it is already connected with the user who owns the scheme. The application makes use of node-oracledb only when login, it validate the oracle user and its password, then close the connection and deliver the requests to the typeORM pool.

Comment: well, in your case it is a bit tricky. you can try to see whether `dbms_session` package can server your purposes, but you will need to create a context in the database. The problem is that for end-to-end tracking in Java, you need to do something that I believe it is not possible with `TypeORM`. This is a good article about it, but I don't think it will solve your issue: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dbms_session#client_identifier